# How to return a custom 401 Unauthorized response spring boot 3.1.2 and Spring Security

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I am updating my project to remove depricated code meant to be removed in my Spring Security Config class.

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("customAuthenticationEntryPoint")
public AuthenticationEntryPoint authenticationEntryPoint;

@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
            //Disable cors headers
            .cors(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
            //Disable csrf protection
            .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
            .authorizeHttpRequests()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .sessionManagement()
            .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
            .and()
            .oauth2ResourceServer()
            .jwt()
            .and()
            .authenticationEntryPoint(authEntryPoint);

    return http.build();
}
```

This works and returns a custom response as on the `authenticationEntryPoint(authEntryPoint)`.

I have updated the filter chain to the below but on 401 Unauthorized returns a blank response body but everything else works well.

```
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
            //Disable cors headers
            .cors(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
            //Disable csrf protection
            .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
            //Authenticate HTTP endpoints
            .authorizeHttpRequests(authorize -> authorize
                    .anyRequest().authenticated())
            //Sessions should be stateless
            .sessionManagement(smc -> smc
                    .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
            .oauth2ResourceServer((oauth2) -> oauth2
                    .jwt(Customizer.withDefaults()))
            //Custom exception response for 401 Unauthorized
            .exceptionHandling(exception -> exception
                    .authenticationEntryPoint(new CustomAuthenticationHandler()));
    
    return http.build();
}
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: What about `.oauth2ResourceServer((oauth2) -> oauth2.jwt(Customizer.withDefaults()).authenticationEntryPoint(new CustomAuthenticationHandler()))`?

Comment: This worked @DirkDeyne - Submit answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Configure your `CustomAuthenticationHandler` on the `oauth2ResourceServer`

like:

```java
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
            //Disable cors headers
            .cors(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
            //Disable csrf protection
            .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
            //Authenticate HTTP endpoints
            .authorizeHttpRequests(authorize -> authorize
                    .anyRequest().authenticated())
            //Sessions should be stateless
            .sessionManagement(smc -> smc
                    .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
            .oauth2ResourceServer((oauth2) -> oauth2
                    .jwt(Customizer.withDefaults()
                    .authenticationEntryPoint(new CustomAuthenticationHandler()));
    
    return http.build();
}
```